# Open excel in a SharePoint with VBA in edit mode

Tags: excel, vba, webdav

I want to edit an Excel stored on a SharePoint but the file can't be modified.

I use this code to open the distant file and edit:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim destFolder, fs, f
    Dim ptrFile
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set destFolder = fs.GetFolder("\\servername@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\")
    For Each f in destFolder.files
        Set ptrFile = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=f.path, UpdateLiniks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways, ReadOnly:=False, Notify:=False)
        ptrFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Hello World !"
        ptrFile.Save
        ptrFile.Close
    Next f
End Sub
```

The file is well opened and modified but it's not correctly saved on the server side.

Is anyone has an idea ?